# How to algebraically find $z$ satisfying $|z-a-ib|=|z-b+ia|$ and $\arg(z-a-ib)=\arg(b-ia)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

How to algebraically find $z$ satisfying

\begin{cases}
|z-a-ib|=|z-b+ia| \\ 
\arg(z-a-ib)=\arg(b-ia)
\end{cases}

Note: $b>a>0$.

### Attempt

Using geometry approach, I find that locus of the first equation is a perpendicular bisector of a line joining $p=a+bi$ and $q=b-ia$. The second locus is a line from $p=a+bi$ in the direction of arrow pointing from $o=0+0i$ to $q=b-ia$. The intersection of these loci is the required $z=p+q=a+b+i(b-a)$ where $opqz$ is a square.

I am interested in the algebraic approach but it looks too complicated. Any hint leading to a much simpler calculation is welcome.

\begin{cases}
|(x-a)+i(y-b)|=|(x-b)+i(y+a)| \\ 
\arg((x-a)+i(y-b))=\arg(b-ia)
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=(x-b)^2+(y+a)^2 \\ 
\frac{y-b}{x-a}=-\frac{a}{b}
\end{cases}

Eliminating $y$, I have

\begin{gather}
(x-a)^2\big(1+(a/b)^2\big)=(x-b)^2
+\big(a+b-\tfrac{a}{b}(x-a)\big)^2\end{gather}

It looks too complicated.

Comment: Given that the algebraic approach looks too complicated to you, let me suggest that the best way to write your post is to show us what you tried and where exactly it got too complicated for you. Otherwise we don't know what "much simpler calculation" even means to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you mean the algebra is too complicated - there is a lot of cancellations to work with. Expand the first equation:
$$ax + by = bx - ay\iff x = \dfrac{b+a}{b-a}y $$

Plug this in to your second equation to get:
$$\dfrac{y-b}{\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}y-a} = -\dfrac{a}{b}\iff b(y-b) + a\left(\dfrac{b+a}{b-a}y-a\right) = 0\implies y = b-a.$$
and so it turns out $x =a+b.$

Comment: I see. I did not expand the first equation so it made complicated.